# Is there anyway to fix this wine problem?

Tags: wine

Picture says it all. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click the *setup.exe* and on **permissions** tab, tick **execute** checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

If the file you are trying to run is on a CD, then you need the CD mounted in a specific way to make these executable files.

Probably the easier way would be to open a terminal, move to the directory that has the executable file, then type in `wine ./filenametorun.exe`.

I don't quite understand why, but the command line will work if double-clicking doesn't.

Comment: That's because the .exe is just a parameter to the wine program - which IS marked as executable.